# How to call rest api on button click in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular app, at the moment it has some data coming in from a rest api. I want to just call that api on a click function, what would be the correct way to implement this?

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.scss']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  public data = [];
  public apiData: any;

  constructor(private service: ApiService) { }

  private getAll() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.getAll();
  }

  onClick() {
    this.getAll()
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="jumbotron hero">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-4 text-center header mb-5">SEARCH</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Search</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputPassword2"
              placeholder="Search iTunes...">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <button (click)="onClick" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Get All</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" >
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
      <tr>
        <th>Artwork</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let user of data">
        <td><img src="{{user.artworkUrl60}}"></td>
        <td>{{user.artistName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.collectionName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.primaryGenreName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.collectionPrice}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is because you are calling `this.GetAll()` in the ngOnInit() function. This is why it already shows in the page before they hit the button.You are basically calling this as soon as the component loads, then again when the user clicks the button. So just remove the call from the `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the **`(click)`** event handler and call **`getAll()`**

```
<button (click)="getAll()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Get All</button>
```

Remove the function call on the **`ngOnInit()`**

in the component.ts

```
getAll() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((results) => {
      console.log('Data is received - Result - ', results);
      this.data = results.results;
    })
}
```

Comment: But, the data is already displayed on the page, I only want the data, when the user clicks the button?

Comment: @Sole that's because you're calling get all in ngOnInit.

Comment: Please see code update, this code is not working either

Comment: your updated code is wrong, change from onClick to getAll. <button (click)="getAll()"

Comment: dude! you are confusing things. just have getAll method in your .ts file and call it as i mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
  <button (click)="onClick" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Get All</button>

  to 

    <button (click)="onClick()" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Get All</button>
```

onClick() is not variable it is method here.

Comment: So the problem is the data just flashes on screen and goes away like a page load

Comment: you mean to say data now coming on button click and goes away after flashing on the screen. Do you see any error on console on inspect ?